# How to activate FastCGI Process Manager (FPM) in Xampp?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have just installed a recent version of Xampp on my Windows 10 laptop. PHP was installed separately (and earlier).

I am learning about PHP and read about the [FastCGI Process Manager](http://www.lolart.net/blog/ez-publish/php-fastcgi-fpm-et-apache) (post written in French). It says that FPM has been included natively since PHP 5.3.3 and that it is recommended to use it.

PHP info tells me that my version is 5.6.11, but that the Server API is Apache 2.0 Handler.

[image]

I am assuming that FPM is not enabled on my installation. How can I enable it? I have been searching for fpm modules in `c:\xampp` and `c:\php`, but cannot find anything.

Comment: Does it distribute `php-fpm.exe`? If it doesn't, you can't enable it. If it does, the Apache configuration is the same as for everyone else, and not XAMPP-related.

Comment: I can't find php-fpm.exe, so what is the next step to have it on my laptop? But it has a php-cgi.exe.

Comment: Compile it from source, or find a package that has it. (But what's the purpose of this switch anyway? FPM may be "recommended" - but that only pertains real servers, not local toy / development setups.)

Comment: Ok. I thought it might be nice to have the same dev and prod environment, but may be that's overkill.

Comment: Yeah. The differences aren't noticeable enough for most web apps (just response headers and .htaccess vs .user.ini configuration). FPM provides a bit less functionality than mod_php even. The SAPIs are abstract / generic enough that you can hardly tell from within PHP scripts or environment vars.